# Create a dynamic function call in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I need a way to write a command call that will be executed in compiled code. However, the command will be store in a database as a String because it's configurable by the user. Each command would match a class but there could be multiple commands that need to be executed with input parameters.

How is the best way of handling this?

Example Class that would be called:

```
public class CreateUser {
   protected User user; 

   public static void create(User user){
      CreateUser cu = new CreateUser(user);
      cu.newUserFunction();
   }

   public CreateUser(User user){
      this.user = user;
   }

   public void newUserFunction(){
      doSomething();
   }
}
```

Example Method that would call the command:

```
public void createUser(User user){
  dclCommand.createUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());

  // Get special commands to run after user is created
  List<Command> cmds = this.dbRepository.findCommand(database, Method.CREATE_USER);
  for(Command cmd : cmds){
     // Here is where the cmd will be executed with input parameters
     // In example the command executed would be 'org.example.CreateUser.create(user)'
  }
}
```

The call to 'org.example.CreateUser.create(user)' will be stored in a database and I need to be able to run it from a function that will get it out of the database and call it adding the parameter User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)?

Basically, you create an interface like

```
interface DoStuff{
    void doIt();
}
```

Then, for every method that the user could call, you create class that implements that interface. Each implementation^ calls their associate method in the body of their `doIt()` method. Then, you store each user's chosen implementation class's [cannononical name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getCanonicalName%28%29) as a string field in the database. When the user logins you fetch than field, instantiate the instance using [Class.forName(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29), and cast the return to `DoStuff`. Then, whenever the user's chose method would be called call `userStuffDoer.doIt()` and their chosen method will be called.

If there is a near infinite number of methods a user could call you will have to use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) and store class and method names and how to get the method data etc.

^ The implementation classes will need to have empty constructors.

Comment: Using your suggestion I created a factory class that created command classes that implemented the 'DoStuff' interface. So I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you implement [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)? You can have the factor to build up the command. This factor would take in the command that you will fetch from database and then based on this command, it would return you a class. You can simply call `returnedObj.execute()`.

For list of commands, you can extend your factory to return command or list of commands based on your inputs.

Your command classes would use "Reflection" to call and execute the method stored in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [Janino's expression evaluator](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Basic) or [embed Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy). These are especially useful as you do not need to compile any Java code - it is compiled at runtime.

Comment: +1 for embedding groovy - this has to be the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use  reflection to create command objects and execute their methods. I would choose it if amount of commands is not so big,  and they do not change a  lot.

Another soluton would be some JVM scripting language ( I recommend groovy )  which would just evaluate scripts coming from database. This is more flexible and allows for command change on the fly without restarting / redeploying server.  ( Used this solution to remote config  DSL routers for some 4+ million of customers every night )

Answer (score 0):

Java is not a dynamic scripting language. To accomplish what you are trying to do you'd need to compile the code retrieved from the DB in memory using the [JavaCompiler Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)

This should get you pointed in the right direction:

http://www.accordess.com/wpblog/an-overview-of-java-compilation-api-jsr-199/

That being said, be very, very careful about how you approach this. Running user-defined code is always error prone.

Comment: Java is also dynamic - there is a ton of scripting languages running from JVM,  and groovy would be able ton evaluate plain hava code / no need to use compiler interface.

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda - It would appear you need to learn the difference between a language and a virtual machine, and to read what the OP is asking. He's not using groovy, he's using Java. Thanks for the downvote though!

Comment: Pure java solutions allowing byte code manipulation at runtime are around since 5-7 years - so language is not as static as C++.   And for original question ,  he could use reflection but evaluating  groovy script would be easier to program.  I tried to use javac at some time for similar task  ( evaluating inetrnal Diablo 2 scriptlets ;) ),  but there was no compiler interface back then.